# How to display dynamic multiple label in tableview cell swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm trying with `NSMutableAttributedString` but not getting perfect resolution and also underline for each string.

**Now It's display like this:**

[image]

**But I want like this:**

[image]

I m trying with this code in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` for displaying the cell:

```
let arrSearchTag = search_detail?.value(forKey: "search_tags") as! NSArray
if arrSearchTag.count > 0
{
    let str : NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
    for string in arrSearchTag
    {
        let myString = string
        let myString1 = "  "
        let myAttribute = [NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.init(red: 94.0/255.0, green: 94.0/255.0, blue: 94.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)]
        let myAttribute1 = [NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.clear]
        let range = (myString as! NSString).range(of: myString as! String)
        let myAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as! String, attributes: myAttribute)
        let myAttrString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString1 , attributes: myAttribute1)

        myAttrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.white, range: range)

        str.append(myAttrString)
        str.append(myAttrString1)

    }
    cell.lblSearchTags.attributedText = str
}
```

Comment: They appeared to be same.

Comment: try to use https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView or https://github.com/zekunyan/TTGTagCollectionView

Comment: yes, I already use this. please go through @Vinodh answer it's useful.

Comment: Ok, I will try this. I think it's very thankful. Thanks.